# Encrypt file from Aurora to S3 using SSE-KMS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, amazon-kms, select-into-outfile

I'm using SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 to move data from Amazon Aurora to S3. The file needs to be encrypted using a KMS key I generated (customer managed).

I'm using OUTFILE S3 command but getting this error -
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SSE_KMS ['abc-1234-pqr-1234-ddddddddd']'

I have changed encryption of bucket to SSE-KMS.
Reference document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

```
select * from table  LIMIT 5 
INTO OUTFILE S3 'https://mybcuket.s3.amazonaws.com/testdata'
ENCRYPTION ON SSE_KMS ['abc-1234-pqr-1234-ddddddddd']
```

What am I doing wrong ?